# Same connection strings, same server, different databases with different results

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-membership

I've 2 MSSQLDatabase in my web host and two connection strings. 
One of them working good. Connecting to server and fetching data.
But other one (which is membership provider) doesn't work anyway. 
My first try was
Generated script via Management Studio wizard and implement it for remote database.
getting : 
**A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)** 
Second was : backed Up my database and sent via ftp. Support team restored my database from bak file. But no luck again. Getting same error My host firm does not provide any remote connection. (for run aspnet_regsql.exe)

Any help?

Comment: It looks like your application is unable to get to the database.
Please verify if the the application has a user id and password that it needs to connect to the database is working fine!

Comment: Yes..Did not see that my role provider name is not defined. With this Application creating 2 application name.. no problem In Production server..but in Host Server getting error. All day lost but other all day saved..Thank you..